# Host cannot communicate with app running inside LXC container

Tags: containers, port, lxc, lxd

I am running on my personal machine with Ubuntu 18.04 multiple lxc containers. Each container has Ubuntu 18.04 as well. For each container I am running an application which offers a UI on https://localhost:3000/. Since every container has a local IP address in my network then I should be able to call forth the application UI on my host machine using https://:3000/ .

This doesn’t work. If I run Apache2 inside the containers, I can see the default page for http:// but nothing on the other application running on port 3000. I can confirm the app on port 3000 is working.

```
user@pc:~$ nc -zv 10.155.120.175 22
Connection to 10.155.120.175 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
user@pc:~$ nc -zv 10.155.120.175 3000
nc: connect to 10.155.120.175 port 3000 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

I also noticed that the application logs inside the VM contained this line, but I dont know what it means in the context of app health.

```
Nov 17 20:38:49 server systemd[1]: app.service: Failed to reset devices.list: Operation not permitted
```

How can I enable ip:port access between host and lxc vm (and between lxc vms)? I want my lxc instances to be able to communicate with each other and my main host, exchange data etc.But I cant even open the UI of an app running inside a container on my browser.

Edit:

When I enable ufw in the container not even the default apache2 webpage opens anymore. Once I disable ufw in the container apache2 page becomes accessible again via

Comment: `I am running an application which offers a UI on https://localhost:3000/` → Application should listen `https://0.0.0.0:3000/`

Comment: I tested this as well (0.0.0.0 instead of localhost) and nothing changes.